# Filtering links/contents in multiple divs on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

I am currently struggling at filtering multiple contents inside multiple boxes.

- I have links/buttons associated with some people names in the top part.
- I also have a side bar with different divs, ranging from A to D(arbitrary).
- Inside those divs, I got those same names in different

What I want to do is basically to show in the different divs (A to D) ONLY the person you clicked on in the top part. and obviously being able to click on others and do the same. At the moment, the first click seems to do what I want but the subsequent clicks do not and everything vanishes.

I can't figure what to do. The project got many different type of filtering and none gave me trouble but this one...

```
  <div id="sidebar_wrapper">
<div class="sidebar_nav">
  <div class="name_icon_box">
    <a href="#" class="icon_all" id="icon_all">ALL</a>
    <a href="#" class="henry" id="henry">HENRY</a>
    <a href="#" class="john" id="john">JOHN</a>

<div class="company_box_white box_a">
    <div class="company_box">
      <div class="button-list"><span class="white_letter">A</span><span class="arrow_menu"></span></div>
      <div class="company_box_list">
        <ul class="name_icon">
          <li><a href="#"><p data-key-value="robert">robert</p></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><p data-key-value="henry">henry</p></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><p data-key-value="steve">steve</p></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><p data-key-value="dean">dean</p></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the code seems to be too big to be posted as is, here is a fiddle link.
https://jsfiddle.net/6sku2ro5/1/

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the functions as they are or can we modify the whole JS code?

Answer (score 0):

I've used hide and show the text in the below boxes based on click of the name in the initial box.

Few things in your code corrected and now the relevant name selection matched will be displayed in each below box.

```
 if (p_data_value == currentPerson || currentPerson == "icon_all") {
      //$(allBoxArr[index]).find('li').find('p').append(p_content);
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sku2ro5/4/)